# How do i preserve form input - after submiting form with dynamic menu list ?? Zend framework

Tags: forms, zend-framework, preserve

Im trying to preserve the user inputs from dynamic menu dropdown lists - I have an number of drowpdowns and a user input text field , when the user submits the form after selecting the options from the dropdowns.

I would like to be able to preserve the last choices made so the user does not have to reselect the options again when re posting the form with another value in the text field, i would also like this to work on errors as well ?

Im using ZF to validate the form.

i have tried the follwing code in the value attr of the option:

```
            <option value="<?php if ($_POST && errors) {
         echo htmlentities($_POST['CategoryID'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
            }?>">Main Category</option>
```

But does not seem to work ?

I have a static options "Main Category" ect. which is what the form defaults to after submiting

can anyone help me on this one ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Also do you use Zend_Form?

Comment: If you want to preserve the values of the GLOBAL ($_POST) variable you need to have trapped its value on the fist page visited after the form has been submitted otherwise the $_POST values would be lost. I don't know how your form submits but this much I can tell you

Comment: And besides, if you are using Zend_Form full fledged, ZF takes care of this for you when you validate the form using the isValid() method of the form object

Comment: Thanks, no not using zend_form , im using a html form and zend_validate , the form is a POST method and submits data to a mysql data base , the form action is back to itself after submiting, its at this point that i would like to keep the original data from the selected dropdowns. if im not making sense please tell me ! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend using Zend_Form. If that is not possible, I would next use [Zend_View Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial) to build your HTML manually. Then you can use the `formSelect` in your view like this:

```
echo $this->formSelect('CategoryId', $selected, $attribs, array(
         'main' => 'Main Category'
         // ... other options
     ));
```

Where `$selected` variable equals to one of the following: posted value(s), default value(s), or is null and `$attribs` variable is simply attributes for the select element.

Comment: Thanks, i've looked at zend_form and will try this as it seems to give me what i want, ive always been confused with the term "view" waht dose it mean ?

Comment: Read [Zend Framework & MVC Introduction](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html)

Comment: have bought a book and read some tutorials, think ive got it now, not sure ZF is for me ? bit above my ability !